# How do I access incubatee value in vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js, axios

I am writing a vue app and I am getting my data from an api

I want to show the name of the person that asked the question

Here is the data

```
{
    "success":true,
    "questions":[
        {
            "id":"1994db8a-66fb-43d8-aec8-290957dd9bcc",
            "incubatee":{
                "id":"ec58948b-64a7-4fa8-a438-baf6b016cdc3",
                "user_id":"ee40dd45-1bc4-449a-ad69-e46a3e11e6fe",
                "name":"Okafor Nnamdi",
                
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my vuejs code

```
<template>
         <div v-for="(question, index) in allQuestions" :key="index" class="d-flex question-section">
                <img src="@/assets/images/auth_background.png" alt="">
                <div  class="question" >
                  <div class="__heading">{{question.incubatee.name}} <span class="__time"> ago</span></div>
                  <div class="__body">
                    {{question.question}}
                  
                    <div class="__view-reply">
                        <span>View Reply</span>
                        <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </template>
```

The code that fetches the api

```
<script>
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import axios from 'axios';
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
onMounted(() => {
  axios.get(route.params.id).then(res => {

        const {data} = res.data.questions;
        // console.log('heyyyyyyyy',res.data.questions);
        allQuestions.value = res.data.questions;
        console.log("All Questions ", allQuestions.value);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err.response);
        const {message} = err.response.data;
        NotificationService.error(message || err.response.statusText);
      });
 }

return {
      askQuestion
    }
}
});
</script>
```

I am getting error that comment.incubatee is null

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: In the code you posted incubatee isn't set to any default value, the only reason why it can be null is that it's received this way.

Comment: @EstusFlask incubatee in the json I posted has a value. which can be accessed the component mounts. I can access the question id but I cant access the incubatee values which displays null

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. There could be other reasons that you possibly didn't show, but it's exactly as I said, incubatee can't be null unless it's explicitly set to null.

Comment: You posted data of `questions` but your template references `comment`. Could you please provide the code where you set your `comment`variable?

Comment: @D.Schaller I have updated my code

Comment: try `v-for="(question, index) in data"`